# Rationale for JetLang (Threadless Concurrency) vs Java Executor

Tags: java, concurrency, messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is messaging (e.g. JMS) an alternative for multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592757/when-is-messaging-e-g-jms-an-alternative-for-multithreading)

I would like to use JetLang in a project. I know that, JetLang belongs to the class of threadless (messaging based) concurrency mechanisms like Erlang, Scala Actors etc. But beyond that, I am unable to rationalize its use against the built in Executors in JDK.

Can somebody please articulate?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592757/when-is-messaging-e-g-jms-an-alternative-for-multithreading

Comment: would even say it's a duplicate ...